# Failed to precompile ZMQ

Tags: zeromq, julia, jupyter, precompile, ijulia-notebook

Any idea how this error could be fixed?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried what's suggest by the first error message? `Pkg.build("ZMQ")`

Comment: Also note it's `Pkg.update()`. I've also seen this error. Sometimes you just need to update, or `exit()` and try again.

Comment: Try `Pkg.build("ZMQ")`, as @Chisholm suggested, and report any error messages here. A "simple" solution could be to try deleting your whole `.julia` directory and reinstalling the packages.